# Is there a generic approach to develop Amazon Echo skills and Google Home actions?

Tags: node.js, web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo, google-home

Is there a generic approach to develope Amazon Echo skills and Google Home actions?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Some sort of cross-platform service that can generate both an Alexa skill and a Google Home action from your code? If so, I think the answer is 'no', unfortunately. The APIs are very different and don't cross over easily.

Answer (score 1):

[API.AI](https://api.ai/) has integrations with both Alexa and Google Home, plus [more](https://docs.api.ai/docs/integrations).

API.AI is a natural language understanding platform that makes it easy to design and integrate intelligent and sophisticated conversational user interfaces into mobile apps, web applications, devices, and bots.

Their Alexa integration feature allows you to export your agent as Alexa compatible files, which include Intent Schema and Utterances.

With Actions on Google integration, you can preview your Conversation Action with the Google Home Web Simulator and deploy your agent so that other users can discover and use it on the Google Home.

Answer (score 1):

[Jovo](https://www.jovo.tech/) is a new Open Source framework for developing cross platform voice apps.  It supports both Amazon Alexa Skills and Google Home Actions.